# PhoneGap Build 3.0.0

Tags: ajax, cordova

I want to take data from my Phonegap Build App and add to my MySQl database using a server-side script. I had this working 100% fine on Phonegap 2.7 but now they have upgraded Phonegap 3.0.0 and it will not even get to the .php script on the server.

My AJAX code:

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    cache: false, 
    url: "http://domain.com/myfile.php", 
    data: {"Lon":  PGLon , "Lat": PGLat , "Altitude": Altit , "Accuracy": Accur , "AltitudeAcc": AltitudeA , "Heading": Headi , "UUID": PGUUID , "Name": PGNAME , "Speed": Speed , "Timee": Timee , "App": PGUUID} , 
    dataType: "text", 
    success: function(data) { 
    $('#thediv').text("Update Done");}, 
    error: function(e){ <br>
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
</script>
```

I can submit data from another server to this script fine `myfile.php`, but just cannot from my app now. I have setup the log on my script on the server to watch for connections to the server but don't see any made from the app.

I have also setup access origin=".*"/ in the `res/xml/config.xml`.

Comment: Is your access origin tag set to `".*"` or to `"*"` (without the . in front)?

Comment: I tried both but it is currently "*"

Comment: Do you get any errors from the console? What about ANdroid errors from logcat?

Comment: In Logcat it says "WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked" but I can not find why or how to un-block.